# HTML dropdown to update table

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do might be impossible, but I've come to the conclusion that I'm chasing my tail a bit.  I've created the following php to populate a dropdown with a list of performances:

```
echo '<select id="tunelist" name="tunelist" >'; 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'setlist', 'music');
$query = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['Database'].'">'.$row['Database'].'</option>';
}
echo '</Select>';
```

After a selection has been made I would like to display information from the selected database in a table below the dropdown.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be accomplished?

Thanks,

Loren

Comment: I think you can use AJAX and do same thing.

Comment: It would be wiser not to use `mysql_*` functions, anyway.

Comment: On the title, you said you want to update table. At a glance, it means you may want to update a Database table. But later, you said you want to display information in a table below the dropdown (perhaps, it is HTML page on the page). To get clear answer, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in PHP, you have to do it with JavaScript/jQuery, and use a technology like AJAX.

You should create another div with id `selected-div` and something like this using jQuery:

```
$("#tunelist").select(function(e) {
    // fill the div here
    $("#selected-div").text("You selected: "+$(this).val())
});
```

You can check out jQuery here: http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: Would the div contain the combo? or would the combo on change call "e"?

Comment: No, that `<div>` is not the combo div. And 'e' can't can be called as it is an argument to a function. No offense, but it looks like you don't know much about JavaScript, you should learn it if you want to do serious web development, then you will understand what I mean.

Comment: you are right.  I'll do some reading and look for some tutorials to see what I can try and learn.